# Sanitize Strings for Legal Variable Names in PHP

Tags: php, string, class, variables, sanitization

I have code something like the following, which declares a class and its name is based on a retrieved string. But the problem is that the string may contain illegal characters that PHP doesn't accept as a class name. So is there a good way to sanitize the string before using it as a class name?

```
$retrieved_string = 'some unformatted string; it may contain illegal characters to be passed as a class name.';

$strMyScript = basename(__FILE__, ".php"); 
$strMyScript = sanitize_variable($strMyScript);
$strClassName = sanitize_variable($retrieved_string);

eval('
    class ' . $strMyScript . '_' . $strClassName . ' extends AnotherClass {
        // some code here
    }
');

funaction sanitize_variable($string) {
    // sanitize the string
}
```

Comment: Match it against the following regex: `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decide what you need a filter or a validator. A validator will return true/false. Then you can raise an exception, produce an error for the user or just ignore the file. The other option is to use a filter which will effectively remove characters from the input string.

```
public function sanitize($input)
{
    $pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/';

    return preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $input);
}
```

You might also want to check for unicode. The pattern is:

```
public function sanitize($input)
{
    if (!@preg_match('/\pL/u', 'a'))
    {
        $pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/';
    }
    else
    {
        $pattern = '/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u';
    }
    return preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $input);
}
```

Issues also to consider:

- Do you want to enable whitespace support? In this case you will need to add a space in the $pattern variables.
- Are the filenames in a language other than English? Then you will need to do some locale specific manipulation to get the $pattern up to date.

HTH

Comment: It seems my last comment has been removed or it could not be submitted somehow. I never though about Unicode strings may be included. Thanks for mentioning it. I'll look for another another approach like generating a unique id with `uniqid()` from the file modified date so that I don't need to filter strings. Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: I think you mean: return preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $input); (not $value)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a string is a valid identifier (class-, variable- or function name) using

```
if (preg_match("/^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $received_string)) {
    // valid name
} else {
    // invalid name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a regular expression the PHP authors provide, see the [manual entry on classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

```
<?php

if (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)$/', $strClasssName)) {
    // etc.
}
```

It's the same with function names or any other label.

If you're looking to sanitize the string, then maybe you need to remove everything that's not `[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]` and then validate against `^([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)$` (the difference is, while integers are allowed characters, a class/function name may not start with one).

Comment: preg_match( '/^([\w\d_\x7f-\xff][\w\d_\x7f-\xff]*)$/', $strClasssName, $match ))  -- for string capture...

Comment: `\w` contains `\d` and `_` so there's no need to include them. Second, a label may not start with a `\d`, so the first character can't be `\w`. Also, you may want to use the `u` (Unicode) modifier.